# How to give formControlName to a FormArray object - Angular 2 (ReactiveFormsModule)

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, formarray

In my application I made a form using Reactive Forms. In my app their is a button `Add new Fields` upon clicking this button new fields are added.

I am able to add new fields but I am not able to assign `formControlName`.

Could any one please show me the right path how can I add `formControlName` to these dynamically added fields.

[Here is the Plnkr for this.](https://plnkr.co/edit/gFC9ySSTucOhPqzjjiHB)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have `formArray` of array of `FormGroup`.

So use `formArrayName` with loop of `formGroupName` with `formControlName(itemDetail, quantity, rate...)`

```
<table formArrayName="salesList">
    <tr>
     <th>Item Detail</th>
     <th>Quantity</th>
     <th>Rate</th>
     <th>Tax</th>
     <th>Amount</th>
    </tr>
    <!--Input controls -->
    <tr  *ngFor="let saleList of salesListArray.controls;let i = index" [formGroupName]="i">
        <td>
             <div class="col-sm-6">
                 <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Item Detail" formControlName = "itemDetail"/>
             </div>
        </td>
         <td>
             <div class="col-sm-6">
                 <input class="form-control" type="text"   placeholder="0" formControlName = "quantity" />
             </div>
        </td>
         <td>
             <div class="col-sm-6">
                 <input class="form-control" type="text"   placeholder="0.00" formControlName = "rate"/>
             </div>
        </td>
         <td>
             <div class="col-sm-6">
                 <input class="form-control" type="text"   placeholder="Select a tax" formControlName = "tax"/>
             </div>
        </td>
         <td>
             <div class="col-sm-6">
                <span>{{saleList.amount}}}</span>
             </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**[Fixed Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/jdFnKtwb1lRPMERllSMR?p=preview)**

See also

- https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-build-nested-model-driven-forms-in-angular-2
- https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#display-the-formarray

Comment: thanks it is working now. I searched but I havent found any info about how to use formArrayName like this.If possible could you please provide me any link from which I can Learn in detail.

Comment: Plunker link never loads for me :(

Comment: @Crystal I've updated the link https://plnkr.co/edit/jdFnKtwb1lRPMERllSMR?p=preview

Comment: For anyone using `mat-table`, use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51348069/64279) to get the index.