# Angular Material Table Sorting with reactive formarray

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design, material-table, angular-material-table

I am trying to implement sorting / filtering on angular material table with formArray as input data source.

[StackBlits code link](https://stackblitz.com/github/snehalp29/angular-expand-row)

```
dataSource = new MatTableDataSource([]);
<table mat-table [dataSource]="formdataarray.controls" multiTemplateDataRows class="mat elevation-z8" matSort >
<ng-container  matColumnDef="{{column}}" *ngFor="let column of columnsToDisplay" >
<th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>{{column}}</th>
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{ element.value[column] }}  </td>
</ng-container>
```

But Sorting / Filtering is not working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two options here:

- use plain array `formdataarray.controls` as a `dataSource` and implement all DataSource methods like filter, sort by your own. Or write custom CDK DataSource implementation. See also https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-material-data-table/
- use `MatTableDataSource` and adjust filtering and sorting logic to support `AbstractControl` object.

**html**

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource"
```

**ts**

```
ngOnInit() {
  // fill FormArray
  ...
  this.dataSource.data = this.formdataarray.controls;
  this.dataSource.sortingDataAccessor = (data: AbstractControl, sortHeaderId: string) => {
    const value: any = data.value[sortHeaderId];
    return typeof value === 'string' ? value.toLowerCase() : value;
  };

  const filterPredicate = this.dataSource.filterPredicate;
  this.dataSource.filterPredicate = (data: AbstractControl, filter) => {
    return filterPredicate.call(this.dataSource, data.value, filter);
  }
}
```

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-bb7kks?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-expandable-rows-example.ts)**

Also, if you want to add new items to your `FormArray` you should update `this.dataSource.data` as well. See also [Angular Material editable table using FormArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51150193/angular-material-editable-table-using-formarray)

Answer (score 0):

You also needs add event `(matSortChange)=sortTable($event)`

To the `table` tag

And add `sortTable` logic inside components

Comment: Hi I added this event but its still not working can you show on https://stackblitz.com/github/snehalp29/angular-expand-row

Answer (score 0):

> Requires ngAfterViewInit to work

```
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';
import { MatSort } from '@angular/material/sort';

...

@ViewChild(MatSort, {static: false}) sort: MatSort

...

ngOnInit() {
  this.getYourData$.subscribe(d => this.data = new MatTableDataSource(d));
}

ngAfterViewInit(): void {

  this.data.sortingDataAccessor = (data: AbstractControl, sortHeaderId: string) => {
  const value: any = data.value[sortHeaderId];
  return typeof value === 'string' ? value.toLowerCase() : value;
};

this.data.sort = this.sort; // where this.sort defined above.

  this.data.filterPredicate = (data: AbstractControl, filter) => {
  // return true or false on data.
  }
}


... html

<table matSort ...
```