# How to set value in a loop of formControl?

Tags: javascript, angular, input, form-control

I have a mat-table and one of the column heading is having an edit icon/button, on click of which all the values of the third column are converted into input fields. I just want to set the same value in the input fields as well.

I have tried this.

```
 <ng-container matColumnDef="amount">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Amount
        <button mat-icon-button (click)="onEditClick(datasource)">
            <mat-icon style="cursor: pointer;"  class="ml-2 mr-2" >edit</mat-icon>
        </button>
    </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row; let i=index;">
       <ng-container *ngIf="isActual">{{row.amount || "-- --"}}</ng-container>
        <mat-form-field *ngIf="isEditMonth" class="example-full-width month-textbox" appearance="outline">
            <input matInput type="text" [formControl]="amountField" (change)="onAmountChanged($event,row)" [ngModel]=row.amount>
        </mat-form-field>
    </td>
</ng-container>
```

//ts code

```
  amountField = new FormControl('', Validators.compose([Validators.min(0)]));

  onEditClick() {
    if (this.isEditMonth) {
      this.loadCharges();
      this.isEditMonth = false;
      this.isActual = true;
    }
    else {
      this.isEditMonth = true;
      this.isActual = false;      
    }
  }
```

Please check my stackbiltz code.
[enter link description here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ppz3ou?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Please include the relevant code in the question itself rather than an external link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you have to dynamically build a group of FormControls for the available length of your array.

HTML

```
<form [formGroup]="elementForm" id="ngForm" #form="ngForm">
  <div [formGroupName]="'amountFields'">
    <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">

      <ng-container matColumnDef="unit">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Unit.</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.unit }}</td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="accountNo">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Account No.</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.accountNo }}</td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="amount">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
          Amount
          <button mat-icon-button (click)="onEditClick()">
            <mat-icon style="cursor: pointer;" class="ml-2 mr-2">edit</mat-icon>
          </button>
        </th>

        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
          <ng-container *ngIf="isActual">{{ element.amount }}</ng-container>
          <mat-form-field
            class="example-full-width month-textbox"
            appearance="outline"
            *ngIf="isEditMonth">
            <input
              matInput
              appearence="fill"
              type="text"
              [formControlName]="element.accountNo"
              (change)="onAmountChanged($event, element)"
            />
          </mat-form-field>
        </td>
      </ng-container>

      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"></tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</form>
```

TS

```
import { OnInit, Component, VERSION } from '@angular/core';
import {
  FormGroup,
  FormControl,
  Validators,
  FormBuilder,
} from '@angular/forms';

export interface PeriodicElement {
  accountNo: string;
  unit: number;
  amount: number;
}

const ELEMENT_DATA: PeriodicElement[] = [
  { unit: 1, accountNo: 'Hydrogen', amount: 20 },
  { unit: 2, accountNo: 'Helium', amount: 10 },
  { unit: 3, accountNo: 'Lithium', amount: 50 },
];

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;
  isActual: boolean = true;
  isEditMonth: boolean = false;
  amountFieldsFormGroup: FormGroup = this.formBuilder.group([]);
  public elementForm: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    amountFields: this.amountFieldsFormGroup,
  });

  amountField = new FormControl('', Validators.compose([Validators.min(0)]));

  displayedColumns: string[] = ['unit', 'accountNo', 'amount'];
  dataSource = ELEMENT_DATA;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.createFormValues();
    console.log(this.elementForm);
  }

  private createFormValues(): void {
    this.dataSource.forEach((element: PeriodicElement) => {
      this.amountFieldsFormGroup.addControl(
        element.accountNo,
        this.createElementFormControl(element.amount)
      );
    });
  }

  private createElementFormControl(amount: number): FormControl {
    return new FormControl(
      { value: amount, disabled: false },
      { validators: Validators.nullValidator }
    );
  }

  onEditClick() {
    if (this.isEditMonth) {
      this.isEditMonth = false;
      this.isActual = true;
    } else {
      this.isEditMonth = true;
      this.isActual = false;
    }
  }

  onAmountChanged(e, elem) {}
}
```

Change it for your needs...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you press edit, you have formControl and ngModel in your input-element.
Thats why you have a data binding conflict.

So if you remove your formControl, you will get your correct data-binding and it will show correct values.

Comment: Actually, I have to add validations in the input fields. that is why used formControl.

Comment: There are similar questions that can help you implementing a table with editable rows.
Like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51150193/angular-material-editable-table-using-formarray