# Material Table - Add Custom Column that contains inputs to a FormArray

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have a material table that updates its data using filters. One filter pulls records for invoices that are unpaid. For unpaid records, I've added a custom column that contains an input called `payment_amount`. The `payment_amount` field is not part of the table's `DataSource` object. I don't want it to be because I'm using the input to calculate two other fields in the `DataSource`. So the process is when a check comes in, I can input the payment amount, then `rate` and `fuel_surchage` are automatically calculated sending the updated record to the backend.

The problem is the inputs need to be in a FormArray so they have unique references for Validation and values correspond to the record's id.

I don't know where to start adding these input elements to a Form array. I know I need a `FormGroup` but I don't know where to place it, and I know I need to declare a `FormArray` but I'm not sure how to populate it as the table is rendered. Any Ideas?

Here's what I have thus far.

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="payment_amount">
  <th mat-header-cell mat-sort-header *matHeaderCellDef> Payment Amount</th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let shipment; let index = index">
    <mat-form-field>
      <mat-label>Payment Amount</mat-label>
      <mat-icon inline matPrefix fontIcon="attach_money"></mat-icon>
      <input matInput required minLength="300" (blur)="calculateBill(shipment.id,$event.target.value)">
    </mat-form-field>
  </td>
</ng-container>

<ng-container matColumnDef="shipments.rate">
   <th mat-header-cell mat-sort-header *matHeaderCellDef> Rate</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let shipment"> {{shipment.rate | currency}}</td>
</ng-container>

<ng-container matColumnDef="shipments.fuel_surcharge">
  <th mat-header-cell mat-sort-header *matHeaderCellDef> Fuel Surcharge</th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let shipment"> {{shipment.fuel_surcharge | currency}}</td>
</ng-container>
```

In my component;

```
calculateBill(shipment_id, value){
  //calculates the two fields and updates the table cells. Updating the table view works
  let index = this.dataSource.shipmentsResponse.data.findIndex({
    shipment => shipment.id===shipment_id
  });
  this.dataSource.shipments[index].fuel_surcharge = value-300;
  this.dataSource.shipments[index].rate = 300;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `formArrayName="array"` on the table and then create a form control for each row on the table, please find below a working stackblitz

html

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroup">
  <table
    mat-table
    [dataSource]="dataSource"
    class="mat-elevation-z8"
    formArrayName="array"
  >
    <ng-container matColumnDef="payment_amount">
      <th mat-header-cell mat-sort-header *matHeaderCellDef>Payment Amount</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let shipment; let index = index">
        <mat-form-field>
          <mat-label>Payment Amount</mat-label>
          <mat-icon inline matPrefix fontIcon="attach_money"></mat-icon>
          <input
            matInput
            [formControlName]="index"
            (blur)="calculateBill(shipment.id,$any($event!.target)!.value!)"
          />
        </mat-form-field>
      </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="rate">
      <th mat-header-cell mat-sort-header *matHeaderCellDef>Rate</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let shipment">{{shipment.rate | currency}}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="fuel_surcharge">
      <th mat-header-cell mat-sort-header *matHeaderCellDef>Fuel Surcharge</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let shipment">
        {{shipment.fuel_surcharge | currency}}
      </td>
    </ng-container>
    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayColumns"></tr>
    <tr
      mat-row
      *matRowDef="let row; let i = index; columns: displayColumns;"
    ></tr>
  </table>
</form>

<!-- Copyright 2023 Google LLC. All Rights Reserved.
    Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that
    can be found in the LICENSE file at https://angular.io/license -->

{{formGroup.value | json}}
```

ts

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MatCommonModule } from '@angular/material/core';
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import {
  FormArray,
  FormControl,
  FormGroup,
  ReactiveFormsModule,
  Validators,
} from '@angular/forms';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';

export interface PeriodicElement {
  name: string;
  position: number;
  weight: number;
  symbol: string;
}

const ELEMENT_DATA: any[] = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Hydrogen', payment_amount: 0, rate: 0, fuel_surcharge: 0 },
  { id: 2, name: 'Helium', payment_amount: 0, rate: 0, fuel_surcharge: 0 },
  { id: 3, name: 'Lithium', payment_amount: 0, rate: 0, fuel_surcharge: 0 },
  { id: 4, name: 'Beryllium', payment_amount: 0, rate: 0, fuel_surcharge: 0 },
];

/**
 * @title Basic use of `<table mat-table>`
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'table-basic-example',
  styleUrls: ['table-basic-example.css'],
  templateUrl: 'table-basic-example.html',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    MatTableModule,
    CommonModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MatInputModule,
  ],
})
export class TableBasicExample {
  formGroup: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    array: new FormArray([]),
  });
  displayColumns = ['payment_amount', 'rate', 'fuel_surcharge'];
  dataSource = ELEMENT_DATA;

  ngOnInit() {
    const arrayCtrl: FormArray = <FormArray>this.formGroup.get('array');

    this.dataSource.forEach((x: any) => {
      arrayCtrl!.push(
        new FormControl(x.payment_amount, [
          Validators.required,
          Validators.max(300),
        ])
      );
    });
  }

  calculateBill(shipment_id: any, value: any) {
    //calculates the two fields and updates the table cells. Updating the table view works
    let index = this.dataSource.findIndex(
      (shipment: any) => shipment.id === shipment_id
    );
    this.dataSource[index].fuel_surcharge = value - 300;
    this.dataSource[index].rate = 300;
  }
}
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nhe8e4-xjp44e)

---

#### References

1. [form array on angular material table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51150193/angular-material-editable-table-using-formarray)

Comment: This got me  further.  I'm having lifecycle issues where I'm trying to push to the array before dataSource is updated from the filter event.

Comment: The answer is correct. The remaining issues were fixed by connecting to my custom data source and updating the formArray.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late with this solution but I have created a node package for a reusable
table form component that may be of some use to you.
It does not use angular material tables but rather standard html and bootstrap class names for the table. Feel free to use the package as is, or use it as inspiration for your own table form component.

A map of column names and their validator functions are passed in as input, and optionally an array of objects can be passed in as input.
If an array is supplied, this will be mapped to a formArray and rendered on the table.
Each formGroup in the formArray will be mapped to a row in the table.
Each formControl in the formGroup will be mapped to its corresponding column in the table.
An empty row will always remain at the bottom of the table to allow for creating new records.

Table edits are saved when pressing the enter/esc key, when the row loses focus, when tabbing to a new row or when the save button is clicked.

Create, edit and delete events are emitted and can be reacted to as you see fit in your angular app.

Check out the package here https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-table-form

Install the package using this command

`npm install ng-table-form`

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow. Even if you explain that it's your lib, can you add code for the example and I suggest you to don't make a pub of it. I already saw one of your post that seems like that so be careful :)